# Using R, how to change date column in a table from Character to Date format and to make all dates in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: r, date

I am working with a CSV database during my Google Data Analytics Capstone project.

I would like to perform a couple of tasks in R

1. Changing date column string from 'Character' to 'Date'
2. Make date column formatting consistent in mm/dd/yyyy format. Some of the fields in the column are in mm-dd-yyyy format

Table sample:

| Id | ActivityDay | Calories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1503960366 | 04-12-2016 | 1985 |
| 1503960366 | 4/13/2016 | 1797 |
| 1503960366 | 4/14/2016 | 1776 |
| 1503960366 | 4/15/2016 | 1745 |

**Codes I am using in R:**

```
# Uploading tables for case. Table name = dailyCalories_merged, Column name = ActivityDay
dailyCalories_merged <- read.csv("dailyCalories_merged.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

# Installed necessary packages
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Code for changing format. However, these codes are not giving expected results
# Code 1:
dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay <- as.Date(dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay, format = "%m%d%Y")

# Code 2:
dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay <- as.Date(dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay, format = "%m%d%Y")
```

Both the above codes have changed string from Character to Date however not changed the format of the date to mm/dd/yyyy across the column of the table.

Curious to know what is missing.

Thank you.

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates, or formatting dates into strings for display. If you try to "change" a date's format the best result will be to get back the original date. Worst case, you'll end up storing and using the *wrong* date. Instead of April 1 you'll end up with January 4

Comment: This looks like a type to me Try adding a hyphen
#Code 2: dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay <- as.Date(dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay, format = "%m-%d-%Y")

Answer (score 0):

In R a date is an object so it has nothing to do with the format. If you display a date on screen or save it to csv, it will take the format used in your local settings, most likely YYYY-MM-DD.

If you want a date displayed in a specific format you have to either change your settings (not recommended) or read it as a date, to be sure that the dates are properly formatted then make the column a string again by formatting the date into a specific format.

What you're doing while using `as.Date(dailyCalories_merged$ActivityDay, format = "%m%d%Y")` is telling R that the column must a Date column and the format used to read the data is %m%d%Y. Do it, check that the date is properly formatted by checking if there isn't any NA after the as.Date operation, then format it again as a string and give it the format you want.